# Access to objects

Tags: javascript

Iam seeing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in console every time Iam trying to access objects. can anyone pls help me where I am doing wrong.

```
function deleteButton() {

   let deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.products ion-icon');
   let productName;
   let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
   let cartItems =localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
   cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    console.log(cartItems);  

    for(let i=0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {

        deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click',() => {
        productName=deleteButton[i].parentElement.textContent.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
        console.log(productName);
        console.log(cartItems[productName].name);       

     });
    }
    }



 console.log(cartItems);  // console.log is printing as 
  {naturalStraight: {…}, naturalWavy: {…}}
   naturalStraight:
   incart: 2
   name: "Natural Straight"
   price: 95
   tag: "naturalStraight"
    proto__: Object

  console.log(productName);// it is printing as 
   naturalstraight

    console.log(cartItems[productName].name); // this is printing an error as cannot read property 
       name
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so "naturalstraight" and "naturalStraight" are two different properties.

Comment: Can you post sample json?

Comment: Also you can't referance those who created inside function scope. so move `cartItems` to top of function

Comment: @JohnMontgomery thx for the reply can you pls let me know how to make both properties same.

Comment: @HalilÇakar you me like this  function deleteButton() {
 let cartItems =localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
 cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

Comment: @madhu The easiest fix would be to just change all the properties in `cartItems` to lowercase. The better fix would be to not try to parse data from your HTML, keep all the relevant data in your JavaScript, and use the index to get the product name instead (or save it to the `cartItems` object if it's always the same every time), but that's a bigger change and depends on how you're building the data in the first place.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thx it is working now

Answer (score -1):

Probably following would work

```
let cartItems;
function deleteButton() {

    let deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.products ion-icon');
    let productName;
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    console.log(cartItems);

    for (let i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
        deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            productName = deleteButton[i].parentElement.textContent.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
            console.log(productName);
            console.log(cartItems[productName].name);

        });
    }
}
deleteButton();
console.log(cartItems);
```